# Javascript querySelectorAll Return Only Selectors I Specify

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I need assistance with `querySelectorAll`. Is there a way to have the function return the elements that only I specify?

i.e. `document.querySelectorAll('span.Fz-xxs')` could return an element `<span class="blah1 blah2 Fz-xxs">` but I just want it to return elements that are `<span class="Fz-xxs">`

Comment: For that you can use: `document.querySelectorAll('span[class="Fz-xxs"]')`

Comment: Perfect! If you submit it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 3):

To select a `<span>` with just the class you want (ex: Fx-xxs) and nothing else, you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span[class="Fz-xxs"]')
```